# perl call variable name using another variable(array)

Tags: arrays, perl

```
my @CLASS_TYPES = ("INTRA", "BB", "CAT");
my @INTRA_NEIGH = ("1.1.1.1/32","2.2.2.2/32");
my @BB_NEIGH = ("3.3.3.3/32","4.4.4.4/32" );
foreach my $class (@CLASS_TYPES) {
    my $csv = @.$class._NEIGH;
    print($csv);
```

when I print $csv I am expecting to print the array values how do I achieve that

Comment: You don't. See [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) and [A More Direct Explanation of the Problem](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html).

Comment: Is `@LSP_CLASS_TYPES` supposed to be `@CLASS TYPES`? It sounds like you really want a [hash](https://perldoc.pl/perlintro#Hashes).

Answer (score 3):

That's not the right approach. See [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) and [A More Direct Explanation of the Problem](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html).

The very fact that `@CAT_NEIGH` doesn't exist illustrates part of the problem.

Solution:

```
my @CLASS_TYPES = ("INTRA", "BB", "CAT");
my %NEIGH = (
   INTRA => [ "1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32" ],
   BB    => [ "3.3.3.3/32", "4.4.4.4/32" ],
);

for my $class (@CLASS_TYPES) {
   next if !$NEIGH{$class};

   print "$_\n" for @{ $NEIGH{$class} };
}
```

or just

```
my %NEIGH = (
   INTRA => [ "1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32" ],
   BB    => [ "3.3.3.3/32", "4.4.4.4/32" ],
);

for my $class (keys(%NEIGH)) {
   print "$_\n" for @{ $NEIGH{$class} };
}
```

Comment: Tip: `[ "1.1.1.1/32", "2.2.2.2/32" ]` can also be written as `[qw( 1.1.1.1/32 2.2.2.2/32 )]`